# Store varied structure in a char*?

Tags: c, string, memory-management, structure

Assuming we have a structure similar to that one:

```
struct tree
{
    unsigned short member1;
    unsigned long member2;
    unsigned char member3;
    unsigned short member4;
};
```

Then, can we use `memcpy` or everything else for that matter to store the entire structure directly in a buffer type `char*` *(Automatized, since the structure could be exclusively large)* ?

Comment: you have gotten 5 correct answers to your question and you have left strange comments... this suggests that maybe your question doesn't express what you are trying to ask. Perhaps update your question with some more examples.

Comment: I don't think i can downvote. Nor i downvoted anything. However if i could.. i would.

Comment: OK...well, someone has gone through downvoting most of them :)

Comment: @Corelation Matt's answer is an exact answer to the question you are asking. I would suggest you accept it and ask a new *different* question, if you want something else.

Comment: And as a hint for the new question, I suggest you provide a complete, compiling code snippet (probably just a `main` function), with non-working part explained in comments (because if you knew how to write it as valid code, you wouldn't need to ask...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is fine and there are no alignment concerns:

```
struct tree leaf = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

char buf[sizeof leaf];   // or malloc
memcpy(buf, &leaf, sizeof leaf);

// do stuff...

struct tree branch;
memcpy(&branch, buf, sizeof branch);
printf("%d\n", branch.member1); // etc.
```

Comment: why would i want to print out the value of member1.

Comment: @Corelation It's just an example showing how to access the values of the struct later. Your question is not very specific so I am assuming you want to be able to retrieve the data that you put into the char buffer.  If you just want to put data in the char buffer and forget about it then disregard the last 3 lines of my code sample.

Comment: But it doesn't work. Note that im using C89.
Accessing the buff's elements separated doesn't return the correct value..

Comment: Also what is that: `struct tree leaf = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };` In C89 at least there is no such way of initializing structures. Shouldn't it be `struct tree leaf[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };` ?

Comment: @Corelation post the code which doesn't work in your question

Comment: No, structures can be initialized from a brace-enclosed initializer list. The values are assigned to members of the `struct` in the order of their declaration within the struct.

Comment: Doesn't work for me anyway. (not like i saw such way in newer languages) I use `struct tree leaf[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };` In newer i use the designated method.

Comment: @Corelation that declares an array of size 1 (it is the same as `struct tree leaf[1]; leaf[0].member1 = 1; leaf[0].member2 = 2; leaf[0].member3 = 3; leaf[0].member4 = 4;`)

Comment: Exactly. I don't have any better way for initializing structures. Such method doesn't exist in C89. So in my case, the structure will be already a pointer if it starts making sense for you.

Comment: @Corelation `struct tree leaf = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };` has been valid since the 1970s. Also you are mixing up arrays and pointers.

Comment: No, Im not mixing up arrays and pointers, Matt.
`struct tree leaf[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };` and `leaf` is a pointer, obviously. `leaf` == `leaf+1`

Comment: No, `leaf` is an array there. Not a pointer. `leaf == leaf + 1` is false also.

Comment: Arrays decay to a pointer.. `leaf` is a pointer to the first element of the array. `leaf+1` same. `leaf+2` Pointer to the second member, assuming the previous was 1 byte. If not.. we can bitshift or do +4.
`leaf+1` is certainly pointer.

Comment: It's an array when it hasn't decayed. `leaf+1` is a pointer but not equal to `leaf`.  Anyway this is getting unproductive; update your question to clarify what you are asking

Comment: `tree == &tree` buddy. Repeating it again. That only IF initialized as an array.

Comment: `tree` is a struct, it can't equal anything. You said `leaf == leaf + 1` .

Comment: Go initialize one array type `struct leaf` then make a simple logical comparison `if(leaf == &leaf)`. See what happans. / `leaf` is the address of the last element in the struct /

Comment: @Corelation you said `leaf == leaf + 1`. This is a different expression to `leaf == &leaf`. IDK why you keep saying "try `leaf == &leaf`", that has nothing to do with what `leaf == leaf + 1` does.   (BTW `leaf == &leaf` is invalid, your compiler must give a diagnostic message).

Answer (score 1):

memcpy() can used as below to copy your structure to `char *array` but the neater way would be to use the same data type to copy during memcpy(). In this case it is better if the destination as `struct tree`

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    struct tree
    {
        int a;
        int b;
    };
    int main ()
    {
     struct tree p1;
     char *p2 = malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
     p1.a =2;
     p1.b =3;
     memcpy(p2,&p1,sizeof(struct tree));
     printf("%d %d",p2[0],p2[4]);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It is already mentioned that this "solution" stands only if the structure is not varied (i.e with homogeneous types). Also your declaration is wrong. It should be just `p1` not `&p1`. `p1` is type `struct` which is sorted like an array. `p1` is a pointer already.

Comment: @Corelation the `memcpy` statement in this code is correct. There is no array declaration. `p1` is not a pointer.

Comment: `p1` already holds the address of the first element of the structure...

Comment: @Corelation no it doesn't, `p1` is the name of a structure and it doesn't hold any address. `&p1` is the address of the structure (which is the same value as `&p1.a`, although different types)

Comment: Yes, initialized like that, but not in my case. Since.. i can't initialize them on that way.. it takes much more time as i said, the structure is large. I use the array method.

Comment: @Corelation What do you mean by "it takes much more time as i said, the structure is large. I use the array method."?

Comment: @Gopi just saying that the structure i have to use is massive and in the sake of the good practice I'm initializing the whole structure as an array of elements. It saves much more time and space.

Comment: @Corelation 2 things 1. Initialize which ever way you want,what has initialization got to do with memcpy()?   2. Using mempcy to copy your struct to char *array can be done the way I have shown.

Comment: @Gopi it has nothing to do with `memcpy()` just pointed out, since you asked.

Comment: @Corelation Please shown your code and what actually you need that will be good, but if we just go by your your current question then the shown code is the right way to do it

Comment: In this code, `*p2 = p1;` would work too, no need for `memcpy`...

Comment: @hyde agree but since he wanted to how to use memcpy() from struct to char * I showed this example

Answer (score 0):

Since memcpy involves two pointers and size, you can do memcpy. But the structure should be word aligned

Comment: I am aware. Thanks. You don't wanna do this with structure, containing 20 elements of all kinds. You don't want to get into such kind of extreme situation.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> #include <string.h>
>  void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          The  memcpy()  function  copies  n bytes from memory area src to memory
>          area dest.  The memory areas must not overlap.  Use memmove(3)  if  the
>          memory areas do overlap.
>
> RETURN VALUE
>          The memcpy() function returns a pointer to dest.

This is taken from the Linux Programmer's Manual (man pages under linux). What it says basicaly is that mempcy function takes two void* pointers and an unsigned int n, and then copies n bytes starting from address pointed to by src to the address pointed to by dest. Because of the nature of pointers, you can cast them however you want (many times with less fortunate results). Your task as a programmer is to cast them "properly" or in a "responsible" manner. For instance you can store an int in a char [4] (on 32 bit systems). Because sizeof(char) = 1, char* is pretty similar with void* in it's core functionality. The big difference (fundamental really) is that you can't dereference a void pointer without a cast. But you can cast it to char* and then dereference it no problem. So yes, you can store your structure in a char * provided you have aloc'ed enough space for it.

Comment: Yes i already know i could do that if all the members are char/char arrays. But.. no. They aren't.

Comment: In standard it is not possible to do pointer arithmetic with void pointers, that is a *gcc* extension. So quite different from char pointer in "core functionality"...

Comment: @hyde you can cast to `char *` and then do arithmetic, to reproduce gcc's functionality, so this is not really a major difference

Comment: @MattMcNabb "You can edit the source code and then it will work", well, I suppose it depends on how you define a "major difference" ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly store the structure values to a buffer by memcpy is that is the whole idea here. E.g.  char buffer[n];  memcpy( buffer, &variableOftree, sizeof(tree));

The risk is that the structure may have variable which is not continuous in memory (unpacked). So you may need to use PRAGMA to pack the structure so that the varaibles are continuos

Comment: Read about strucutre alignment. And how unfortunatelly that won't work. There are a few things i can't actually use due to a platform-dependency and a few other reasons. One of them is the pragma directive.

Comment: Depending on your environment you may have padding bytes in between variables. So we PACK them to avoid padding.